# rails rspec duplicate key value violates unique constraint after adding unique index

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I am working on a rails app, and I added a table. On that table, I wanted an index so to add one, I made a migration for adding a *unique* index. My migration looks like

```rb
class AddIndexToTable < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_index :table, :user_id, unique: true
  end
end
```

everything seemed fine, but now when I run my specs against my migration changes I now get the error

```rb
ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique:
        PG::UniqueViolation: ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "index_table_name_on_user_id"
        DETAIL:  Key (user_id)=(15) already exists.
        : INSERT INTO "table_name" ("user_id", "day", "last_visited_on", "daily_rewards", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6) RETURNING "id"
```

I have tried dropping the DB's, re-migrating, re-setting the pk_sequence with `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.reset_pk_sequence!(table_name)` and other fixes I could find, but I am still stuck on the same error.

Could anyone help me understand why I keep getting this error, and how it can be fixed? I can post more code if needed

Comment: This needs more background info.  How are you seeding the database? Seeds file or Factorybot or what?  Is this happening on a specific test?  What is the setup?  I would look for where you are creating the duplicate data.

Comment: @JoelCahalan I am using factory bot for the data. in terms of the database, I have dropped and re-migrated, so it should be a fresh db with close to nothing in it. the seeds file has not been ran.

Answer (score 2):

You've got either a factory or a test that's trying to create multiple `table` records for the same user.  Either that's going to be obvious looking in the test that's causing this, or perhaps it's an integration test and you don't have your test environment set up properly to clean out the DB between test cases.

Answer (score 0):

For me it was the error that was I allowing the id in the controller params and that I had and `let! create ...` run at every test. So it tried to create again with the same id.

Removing id from allowed params fixed it.